# didn't tell a lie IN / ON any occasion

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Do the following sentences mean the same? Which one among *"in"* and *"on"* is preferably used here?

> 1) He never lied **on/ in** any occasion.
>   2) He didn't tell a lie **on/ in** any occasion.

Answer (score 3):

***On*** is the more common preposition:

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on%20any%20occasion%2C%20in%20any%20occasion&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20any%20occasion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cin%20any%20occasion%3B%2Cc0) *on any occasion vs in any occasion*

[***On*** preposition](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/on):

> - used to show when something ​happens:
>
>   - Hair ​salons don't usually ​open on Sundays.
>   - On a ​clear ​day you can ​see the ​mountains from here.
>   - She was ​dead on ​arrival (= ​dead when she ​arrived) at the ​hospital.
>   - Please ​leave ​your ​key at the ​reception ​desk on ​your ​departure from (= when you ​leave) the ​hotel.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Comment: On isn't the only preposition used to show when something happens.. Her news put me in a difficult situation. He finished his homework in time. I'll go to the party in any event. He never lied in any event/situation.

Comment: @Khan - I agree, but as I said *on* is the more common, especially with the expression *on any occasion*.

Comment: Josh (enthusiasm in Urdu),  I think the sentences quoted by you are not related to the use of the preposition "on" before occasion.  In your sentences, you have used on to refer to a particular time something happens.

Comment: @Khan - isn't an *occasion* a particulat time in which someting happens?

Comment: You are right,. I got it.